# Shopify - Generate pre-order ID and connect with later order id?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template, shopify-api

I want to have a pre-order id, and connect him to a classic order id, and get that pre-order id by order id.
How is that possible?

Actuality, I have created App and connected it to my store, to have one bonus button on a single product page, and whit that button connect ids from above. I am a Shopify app dev beginner, needs resources to learn.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use **note_attributes** property to associate additional information to any order. From [Shopify Docs](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2021-10/resources/order#resource_object) about Order

**note_attributes**

> Extra information that is added to the order.
> Appears in the Additional details section of an order details page.
> Each array entry must contain a hash with name and value keys.

You can add an entry in order like this to associate Pre Order Id to any order.

```
  "note_attributes": [
    {
      "name": "pre_order_id",
      "value": 12345
    }
  ]
```